# Required additional Testing Files in PayPal for mobile app submission

Tags: ios, paypal

I have integrated PayPal's Adaptive payment functionality in my application. However, during app submission, I am asked to upload "Additional Testing Files"/"Ad Hoc Files".

I'm unable to understand what is meant by AdHoc testing files?

Kindly provide me some guidance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They're just wanting to see a demo of the files required to make your app work so that they can run it on the sandbox in order to thoroughly test prior to approving it.

Comment: So do we need to upload coding related files or just screenshots where we have implemented PayPal in our App.

Comment: They're going to want to see code, but a demo video or screenshots is great to provide as well.

Comment: @AndrewAngell... then why they require `test account `credentials if they just need screenshots or code? Where are they going to login for ios app using test account?

Comment: I always say the more you can provide them the better.  Give them the app code.  Let them know what test accounts you're using and provide those credentials.  Provide any screenshots, videos, general docs you can.