# How to submit App to paypal?

Tags: ios, paypal, paypal-rest-sdk

I have Creted an App usnig payPal MPL that use single payment . Now I am creating my Live AppId For paypal from the Paypal.

[image]

I am little bit confuse regarding -

**1 :** (Ad Hoc files required for mobile app submissions). and

**2 :** Supply Test Account Name and Password

I dont have any idea which credential is required here and which file should Upload.

Should I upload ipa file here , I dont know how paypal will review my application.

I need some information on how to submit my App to Paypal . which test credential I can provide to them.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Have a look at this..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27780122/required-additional-testing-files-in-paypal-for-mobile-app-submission

Comment: @RoOmin I have already read this but don't understand his answer.

Comment: I will check it thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**1 : (Ad Hoc files required for mobile app submissions)**:

They dont ask for `.ipa` file here. If you try to upload .ipa file, it will give the following error:

> The selected file yourIpaName.ipa cannot be uploaded. Only files with
>   the following extensions are allowed: pdf, png, jpg, jpeg, doc, docx.

Thus, they need only need a document of the above extension type which can demonstrate where and how you have integrated PayPal. This may include your `paypalcode` and `screenshots` of your paypal screen display output. Create a single document which shows both, I would recommend. Moreover, this field is `not mendatory`.

**2 : Supply Test Account Name and Password**

These are your test account/ sandbox account credentials which you might be using for `payPal` transactions.

Comment: If i am not uploading the ipa file then what is the need of sandbox account id password.?

Comment: @Bhumica I have asked about your query to the answer er of this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27780122/required-additional-testing-files-in-paypal-for-mobile-app-submission

Comment: THanks roomin for help.